# add rows from another table to another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Suppose  i have my table product (id,name,description,image,price) . I have another table product_add (id,name,price).
I have selected all from table product and display it

here are the codes that display all the data from table product

```
    <html>
    <head>     
    <script type="text/javascript" src="add.js"/>
    </head>
    <?php
    include'dbConnect.php';    
    $image =$_GET['image'];
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $name = $_GET['name'];
    $price= $_GET['price'];

    $sql="SELECT * FROM product";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    echo sizeof($result);

    if($result>0){
        echo "<table border='1'>
        <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Image</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Price MUR</td>
        </tr>";

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            extract($row);

            //creating new table row per record
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$id</td>";
            echo "<td><img src=$image  width='120' height='100'/></td>";
            echo "<td>$name</td>";
                echo "<td class='textAlignRight'>$price</td>";
                echo "<td class='textAlignCenter'>";
    ?>
                <input type='button' name='Add_value' value='Add to Cart' onclick='addfunction()'/>
<?php
        }//end while
            echo "</table>";        

    }
    $insert = "INSERT INTO product_add(id, name, price) VALUES ('$id', '$name','$price' ) ";
    $insertQuery=mysql_query($insert);
    ?>
        <div id='ajaxDiv'>Your result will display here</div>
    </html>
```

But the problem is that when I click on the `Add to cart` button, only the last row is being added to the `product_add` table whenever I am adding a particular product to the cart.

Comment: My oh my... you _really_ should kill this code before it hatches: `mysql_*` has been deprecated for a long time. Your code is riddled with injection vulnerabilities and your queries really could do with a bit if work, too.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to write the sql because i dont know it

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't a 1-on-1 tutorial site. I just pointed out that a better understanding of SQL wouldn't hurt. It's up to you to learn. Don't expect copy-paste ready answers here.

Comment: what is the `addfunction()` stated in the `onclick` of your `button` element?